# Multiple XHR request fired using esri/request returning a deferred when handled using dojo/promise/all

Tags: promise, dojo, esri, esri-javascript-api

I am having difficulty while handling multiple XHR request fired using esri/request.

I am firing multiple request using code below

```
var def1 = esriRequest({
   url: url1,
   content: { f: "json" },
   handleAs: "json",
   callbackParamName: "callback"
});


var def2 = esriRequest({
    url: url2,
    content: { f: "json" },
    handleAs: "json",
    callbackParamName: "callback"
});
```

To handle this I am writing following code

```
var promise1 = def1.promise;
var promise2 = def2.promise;

all(promise1, promise2).then(function (results) {
    console.log(results);//here I am getting results as deferred instead of actual result. why?
}, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I am getting results as deferred in the success callback of all above.

Can someone please tell me why I am getting deferred instead of actual results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting results as deferred because I was missing square brackets in the parameters passed to all. The correct way to call all is as follows

```
var promise1 = def1.promise;
var promise2 = def2.promise;

all([promise1, promise2]).then(function (results) {
   console.log(results);
}, function (err) {
   console.log(err);
});
```